# Is there a single word to describe "acting in a way unbecoming of a parent?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

In writing a letter today, I realized I was in need of a word outside my knowledge. I would like to convey that someone acting in a manner unbecoming of parents.

In a world where neologisms were free, I would use "unparently," but I am convinced this is not a Standard English word. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: 'unparently' doesn't sound good to me. Why do you need a single word? You can reword your sentence to allow your descriptive phrase 'unbecoming of a parent'

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used.

Comment: @drgnyc "unworthy," "undeserving"?

Comment: I think it might be better to avoid saying it in the first place, and instead focus on the behaviors that are the problem. My definition of _behavior unbecoming of a parent_ may not be the same as yours.

Comment: I agree with @TimWard as it depend on the kind of behaviour you mean. Sven Yarg's 'Mommy-dearest' would be an abusive parent. But perhaps you mean that parents are acting like children themselves (playing on the roundabout) or setting a bad example (rowing at school meetings). I would say they are 'not setting a good example'. But it's subjective - one parent's liberal style is another parent's lack of a firm hand.

Comment: I would agree that it's probably best to describe the behavior.  And there's essentially zero chance of finding a single word with this meaning, aside from a neologism such as "unparently".

Answer (score 0):

How about

***unpedagogical*** or ***pedagogically unsound***

The term is in keeping with the question's spirit, I think.

While pedagogy is simply the art of teaching, the original Greek word, ***paidagogia***, dating back to simpler times, does mean "education of boys."

The Urban Dictionary assures us that unpedagogical means "the improper practice or demeanour of teaching and instructing, common amongst tertiary institutions."

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Unpedagogical